# Addplot exp dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf

i want to plot 12*(1-exp(-2*x) with little gird,then I try  with  this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=0,ymax=12,no markers,grid=both]
            \addplot {(12*(-exp(-2*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

i have this error message

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@yy
l.157 \end{axis}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error because by default pgfplots will draw your plot on the interval [-5;5], and for x=-5, -12e^10 is too big to handle. To avoid that, you can specify the domain you want, either in the axis or the addplot options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=0,ymax=12,no markers,grid=both,domain=0:3]
            \addplot {(12*(-exp(-2*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```